# Не выводится value на страницу

Tags: javascript, value

Подскажите, в коде ниже почему то не выводится name.value и message.value ?

И если фрагмент кода html выводится из js, как в примере ниже, как добраться тогда до нужного элемента, к примеру кнопка edit ?

```js
const name = document.querySelector('.name')
const message = document.querySelector('.message')
const content = document.querySelector('.content')
const date = new Date()
const arr = []

const text = `
    <div class="contentPost">
        <div class="head-content">
            <div><img src="#" alt=""></div>
            <div>${name.value}</div>
            <div>${date}</div>
            <div><button type="button" class="edit">edit</button> <button type="button" class="remove">remove</button></div>
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/mozilla-firefox-icon-logo-png-3.png" alt="" width="100">
        <p>${message.value}</p>
        <div class="footer-content">
            <a href="#">Like</a> <span>10</span> / <a href="#">Dizlike</a> <span>5</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    `

function contentBlock() {
    if(name.value !== '' && message.value !== '') arr.unshift(text)
    content.innerHTML = arr
    console.log(name.value)
    console.log(message.value)
    name.value = ''
    message.value = ''

}

document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', contentBlock)
```

```css
.head-content {
    padding: 15px 5px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.head-content div {
    margin: 0 25px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial;

}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;
}

.container img {
    float: left;
    padding:0 20px 0 0
}

header {
    height: 10%;
}

footer {
    height: 10%;
}

.contentPost {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: bisque;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.remove {
    width: 90px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: brown;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: black;
}

.edit {
    width: 90px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: olivedrab;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: black;
}

.add-blog {
    width: 90px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: olivedrab;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: black;
}


.head-content {
    margin: 20px 15px;
}

.footer-content {
    text-align: right;
}

.footer-content a:nth-child(1) {
    color: olivedrab;
}
.footer-content a:nth-child(3) {
    color: brown;
}

.content {
    margin: 15px 0;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>BlogTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <header>
        <h3>BlogTest</h3>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="name"><br><br>
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="message"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="file" class="file"><br><br>
            <button type="button" class="add">Add Note</button>
        </fieldset>
    </header>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

</div>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `text` создается в момент выполнения кода один раз. В это время поля ничем не заполнены, поэтому подставляется  пустая строка.

Для решения можно заменить текстовую переменную функцией, которая будет возвращать значение

```js
const name = document.querySelector('.name')
const message = document.querySelector('.message')
const content = document.querySelector('.content')
const date = new Date()
const arr = []

const text = ()=> `
    <div class="contentPost">
        <div class="head-content">
            <div><img src="#" alt=""></div>
            <div>${name.value}</div>
            <div>${date}</div>
            <div><button type="button" class="edit">edit</button> <button type="button" class="remove">remove</button></div>
        </div>
        <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/mozilla-firefox-icon-logo-png-3.png" alt="" width="100">
        <p>${message.value}</p>
        <div class="footer-content">
            <a href="#">Like</a> <span>10</span> / <a href="#">Dizlike</a> <span>5</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    `

function contentBlock() {
    if(name.value !== '' && message.value !== '') arr.unshift(text())
    content.innerHTML = arr
    console.log(name.value)
    console.log(message.value)
    name.value = ''
    message.value = ''

}

document.querySelector('.add').addEventListener('click', contentBlock)
```

```css
.head-content {
    padding: 15px 5px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.head-content div {
    margin: 0 25px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial;

}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;
}

.container img {
    float: left;
    padding:0 20px 0 0
}

header {
    height: 10%;
}

footer {
    height: 10%;
}

.contentPost {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: bisque;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.remove {
    width: 90px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: brown;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: black;
}

.edit {
    width: 90px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: olivedrab;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: black;
}

.add-blog {
    width: 90px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: olivedrab;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: black;
}


.head-content {
    margin: 20px 15px;
}

.footer-content {
    text-align: right;
}

.footer-content a:nth-child(1) {
    color: olivedrab;
}
.footer-content a:nth-child(3) {
    color: brown;
}

.content {
    margin: 15px 0;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>BlogTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <header>
        <h3>BlogTest</h3>
        <fieldset>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="name"><br><br>
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="message"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="file" class="file"><br><br>
            <button type="button" class="add">Add Note</button>
        </fieldset>
    </header>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

</div>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```